# ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

It is my first time to develop the google script for my google sheet

Here is the code of my script

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p3fW0Vkx89tdiws3Z-a5_LpLwyGYj7pacIek3f9Z96w/edit#gid=1862590156'
  var name = '無標題表單 (回應)'
  var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);   
  var values = sheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 1, 1);
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

When I run the script,and then it show the message "ReferenceError: "sheet" is not defined. (第 7 行，檔案名稱：巨集)"

I try to use the method in this article [ReferenceError: "Sheets" is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45625971/referenceerror-sheets-is-not-defined) but still cannot work.
Thank you!

Comment: add line `var sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1')`. Define it first, then use.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

Change `var SpreadSheet` to `var sheet` in the provided code.

---

As the error message is explaining: *The variable `sheet` is not defined in the provided code.*

This means at the point where `sheet` is trying to be used, it does not exist yet. It will have to be defined first.

Try running one of the following before you use the variable `sheet`

```
var sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName('YourSheetName');
```

or using [`.openByUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl)

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
```